# In ranges-v3, how do I create a range from a pair of iterators?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

How do I create a ranges-v3-compatible range, given a traditional pair of "begin" and "end" iterators?

Let's say that I am writing a generic function that accepts two iterators, for compatibility with legacy code.

```
struct result;  

bool keep_line(const std::string&);
result parse_line(const std::string&);

template <typename InputIt>
std::vector<result> parse_lines(InputIt begin, InputIt end)
{
    // This is what I want to do...
    auto lines = ranges::make_range_out_of_legacy_iterators(begin, end);

    return lines 
        | ranges::view::filter(keep_line) 
        | ranges::view::transform(parse_line) 
        | ranges::to<std::vector<result>>();
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To create a range from a pair of iterators in ranges-v3, use the [`subrange` view](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1subrange.html):

```
#include <range/view/subrange.hpp>

auto lines = ranges::subrange(begin, end);       // Requires C++17-style deduction

auto lines = ranges::make_subrange(begin, end);  // If template deduction not available
```

In old versions of the library, the `iterator_range` class in [`range/v3/iterator_range.hpp`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/iterator_range.hpp) was apparently used, but that header is marked deprecated in the current `ranges-v3` release (0.9.1).

Comment: Is it the same for C++20 ranges.

Comment: @L.F.: yes, it should be the same under C++20, based on the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges).  The page for the `subrange` view specifically does not exist on cppreference at this time.

Comment: As a follow-up question, how did you find this out? The reference API you linked seems to contain no reference information beyond the name of the types and methods. Is there some source with actual reference material? I'm exploring the library and I can't seem to find anything that describes the parts of it.

Comment: @Ayjay My recollection is that I searched through [some documentation](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/dir_b00b1d9d00cc44a1bf5374fbcb141bf4.html), and focused on finding a range that had a constructor with the right type signature (accepting an iterator and a sentinel), and was effectively a no-op (as `subrange` is).